# Can HDMI cable + MDP to HDMI Adaptor support 2048 x 1152 on my Macbook Pro 13in (Mid 2010)?

Tags: macbook, resolution, hdmi, external-display, mini-displayport

I'm wondering if I should go with HDMI + MDP2HDMI adapter to get the sound along with video or go with DVI + DVI adaptor... I have the Dell SP2309W which has a resolution of 2048x1152.

Comment: See here http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=860749

Answer (score 0):

Given that [Mini DisplayPort to DVI](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=5998) and [Mini DisplayPort to HDMI](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=5994) adapters are about the same price, it depends on how good you think the speakers are on the Dell display. Personally, I'd go for the Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter plus a pair of external speakers.